# ImportCSV problems with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I imported a CSV to pandas. However, when I try to use various model packages the cannot coerce one of the columns to float. When I try to do it manually I cannot coerce it either. When I try to check the types of all of my columns, I get the error message below. Any idea whats going on?

```
values = pd.read_csv(".../train_values.csv")

values.dtypes()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Comment: Try `values.dtype` (no method parens). That error is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dtypes` is an attribute of the `pd.Series` not a function. You can access the type by running

```
values.dtypes
```